# How to ignore Null values in a CSV columns with pandas while processing the text?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nlp

I have a CSV file and each word in a sentence is represented in cell, with a null cell between each sentence.

[image: CSV snippet file]

My problem is in **run_id** column, after I load the csv file using pandas I separate each sentence using function "get sent from df" but I've a line of assertion that double check that the run_id is unique and =1 but it fails because it take "Null" as a "Null sentence"

Below is a snippet of my code, I hope you can help

**Note : I working on T="test_RE"**

```
def load_dataset(fn,T):

            if T=="test_RE":
          df = pandas.read_csv(fn,
                         sep= ";",
                         header=0,
                         keep_default_na=False)
          df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('unnamed',case = False)],axis = 1, inplace = True)
          df.word_id = pd.to_numeric(df.word_id, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
          df.run_id = pd.to_numeric(df.run_id, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
          df.sent_id = pd.to_numeric(df.sent_id, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
          df.head_pred_id = pd.to_numeric(df.head_pred_id, errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
      else:
            df = pandas.read_csv(fn,
                         sep= "\t",
                         header=0,
                         keep_default_na=False)
      print (df.dtypes)

      if T=="train":
        encoder.fit(df.label.values)
        print('this is the IF cond')
        print('df.label.values. shape',df.label.values.shape)

      sents = get_sents_from_df(df)

      print('shape of sents 0',sents[0].shape)
      print('sents[0]',sents[0])
      print('shape of sents 1',sents[1].shape)
      print('sents[1]',sents[1])

      #make sure that all sents agree on run_id

                assert(all([len(set(sent.run_id.values)) == 1
                    for sent in sents])) **ERROR HERE**
```

the function

```
def get_sents_from_df( df):

      #Split a data frame by rows accroding to the sentences
      return [df[df.run_id == run_id]
            for run_id
            in sorted(set(df.run_id.values))]
```

shape of sent 0 is (10,8) which is correct and the sent[0] is correct

but shape of sent[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvDBt.png) is (0,8) and of course sent[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvDBt.png) isn't printed because it null, I should have sent[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvDBt.png) shape = (6,8) any help ?

Image of Output of print statements:

[image: Output of print stsatemts]

Comment: `[check image below] ` : there no image  and besides that it's always better to post a sample of your input data

Comment: Yea I added it.

Comment: can you post an output?

Comment: @SebastienD posted an image of the output

Comment: On the first place, always prefer code to screenshots. Second, what is your code supposed to do? What is the desired output?

Comment: @SebastienD all I want to do is let it skip the "Null" rows and doesn't count it as sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the blank rows (which contain both None values and empty strings) , why not just do:

```
df = df[df.word.apply(lambda x : len(x)>0)]
```